# Make MAMP local development environment externally accessible?

Tags: mamp, dynamic-dns

Im developing a website that uses a facebook app that only works when the site is externally accessible. So when the site is on a server everything works fine. When im developing locally the app doenst work. How can I make my local development environment externally accessible?

Im using MAMP and my home ISP is Sky.

Ive tried the following from a tutorial but I dont really know if im on the right track or not. Ive registered for an account with http://dyn.com/ and set up a hostname MY-HOST-NAME.dyndns-at-work.com. When I navigate to MY-HOST-NAME.dyndns-at-work.com in my browser I can see the router's start page. However when I look at the url 'externally' with hidemyass.com the message I get is 'The requested resource could not be loaded.'.

As I understand (Im not sure that I do), I need to make my router externally accessible which I was trying to do with the steps above. Then I need to direct the webpage requests to my computer to see it's localhost. Is this at least correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've setup dyndns. If you open whatismyip.com, and if you ping to your personal dyndns address, you should see the same ip address. I don't know why you see the page of your router. That sounds like a security problem. The router should not show anything, because it should not be possible to access the router admin via an outside ip address. Maybe you've set the router to allow this, I think it's not good practise. Maybe your provider has done this?

You need to set portforwarding in your router. The router should send traffic from the outside for port 80 (HTTP) to your computer, or to the (local) IP address of your computer, whatever port MAMP is using for HTTP. Now it just ignores that traffic. Your computer firewall should allow this traffic, but it probably does already.

- Computer from outside world sends request to your IP via HTTP, port 80
- Router receives request and sees it has portforwarding for port 80
- Router forwards traffic to computer 192.168.1.22 (your local computer ip address), port 8888
- Local computer receives request at port 8888, and sends it to MAMP Apache

Comment: "You've setup dyndns. If you open whatismyip.com, and if you ping to your personal dyndns address, you should see the same ip address" I can see my IP address with whatismyip.com, what should this be the same as?

Comment: I only see the router's page when I type in my IP address into the browser locally. When I enter it with hidmyass (effectively externally) then there is no page. Is this a security issue? You said "it should not be possible to access the router admin via an outside ip address" but its not.

Comment: Im trying to set port forwarding in the router from these instructions: http://helpforum.sky.com/t5/Broadband-Setup-Connection-WiFi/Sky-Hub-How-to-Configure-Port-Forwarding/ta-p/707150 How do I find out what my start and finish port should be from this step: http://helpforum.sky.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/1668i8EBA6B44C59D32F5/image-size/original?v=mpbl-1&px=-1

Comment: It might depend on the browser. It knows its outside ip address and might catch local traffic to that. If you cannot access the router admin via an outside ip address, then it's OK.

Comment: Start port for HTTP is 80, from the outside world. MAMP may use 8888. If you use something like localhost:8888 for opening MAMP pages, then it's 8888. With ipconfig (Windows) or ifconfig (MAC/Linux) you can see what ip address your computer has in the local network.

Comment: Yes my local development environment is at localhost:8888, does that mean the start and finish port should settings for the router should be 8888? I tried changing them both to 88 and I get this message: Sorry, The selected service is used by the firewall!

Comment: @jdln - Standard HTTP traffic uses port `80`, so the external port you want is 80. Internally, you forward it to whatever mamp is running on, so `8888`.  You could use alternate ports externally if you router complains, but it shouldn't since that's a standard. You also probably have DHCP on your router, so I'd do hostname instead of IP in case it changes at some point.

Comment: What do you mean 'external port'? How does this relate to the start and end port?

Comment: see the edit of my answer

Comment: Related answer here: http://superuser.com/questions/678339/how-to-find-out-start-port-and-finish-port-settings-for-port-forwarding/678367?noredirect=1#comment858898_678367